# How do you generate datasets from N(0,1) with a specific sample size?

Tags: r, matrix, dataset

I am fairly new to R, so I am unsure of the best way to approach this problem. I have to generate 5000 datasets from N(0,1) with a sample size of 20. I attempted to use a matrix but I do not know if I am doing it correctly.

Here is what I did:

a <- rnorm(100,000)

am <- matrix(a, nrow = 20, ncol = 5000)

Comment: It is almost correct, but use "." instead of ",". in `rnorm`. Or, try the following: `am <- matrix(rnorm(5000*20), ncol=20)` so that the samples are rowwise.

Comment: Then omit the comma in this case. R (and most other programming languages) don't accept a thousands operator. You may use scientific notation instead, e.g. `1e5`.